Auto-replacement of data model references in JSON swagger
Is there easy way to replace all the "$ref": in swagger json file to models which are located at the end of the file in "components": ? Of course it can be another ref to another ref and so on. Is there any option in swagger configuration?
Ex. before:
"schema": {
"$ref": "#/components/schemas/ModelName"
}

After:
"schema": {
"ModelName": {
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"type": {
"type": "string",
"nullable": true
},
"title": {
"type": "string",
"nullable": true
},
"status": {
"type": "integer",
"format": "int32",
"nullable": true
},
"detail": {
"type": "string",
"nullable": true
},
"instance": {
"type": "string",
"nullable": true
}
},
"additionalProperties": { }
}
}


Does this answer your question? -- OpenAPI Specification (YML/YAML) : All $refs replace or expand to its definition (with schema validation)

You can easily do this with www.redocly.com bundle functionality
npx @redocly/cli bundle <api file> --output <where to save> --format json


I have already tried redocly with this command: npx @redocly/cli bundle --dereferenced --output output-file.json json1.json But JSON output only works when there are no circular references. My files will have circular references. With yaml output it works but I need json
